# Cloud Endpoints, Kubernetes and SSL

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am building an app (API) that will be running on the Google Kubernetes engine. I will add a NGINX Proxy (Cloud Endpoints) with SSL such that all external API requests will go through the Cloud Endpoints instance.

Question is, since I already have SSL enabled on the external open interface, do i need to add SSL cvertificates to the Kubernetes engine as well?

Comment: Is your current SSL endpoint present a SSL valid certificate according with your domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Kubernetes Engine, you can use Ingresses to create HTTPS load balancers with automatically configured SSL certificates. [Google-managed SSL certificates are provisioned, renewed, and managed for your domain names.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) Read more about Google-managed SSL certificates [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#managed-certs).

No, “You have the option to use [Google-managed SSL certificates (Beta)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#managed-certs) or [to use certificates that you manage yourself](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#setting_up_https_tls_between_client_and_load_balancer).”

You added a NGINX Proxy (Cloud Endpoints) with SSL, then you do not need to add SSL certificates to the Kubernetes engine as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is becuase all the traffic behind the proxy (GKE/SSL) would be inside a private network and so does not need a SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. All the traffic behind the proxy (GKE/SSL) would be inside a private network and it does not need an SSL certificate.

You can review this Google document for SSL Proxy Load Balancing Concepts. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/